# Rounding up to the nearest whole number

Tags: objective-c, rounding

I've been searching for quite awhile and can't seem to find anything on this. How do I round a number **up** to the nearest whole number? I'm using the number of objects in an array and dividing it by 3. Say [array count] is 10, and I want to get a 4 as the result of 10/3. Or [array count] is 23, and I want to get an 8. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be sure to cast the number you're rounding:

```
int roundedNumber = ceil((double)number/3);
```

Otherwise integer arithmetic will truncate.

Answer (score 2):

ceil() function is what you are looking for.